# Django: Assign user name to object

Tags: python, django

I'm developing a little app but I'm having trouble adding the username of the current user to an object.

I have defined the "message" model with the "author" property

`author = models.ForeignKey(User)`

Then on my view, I have:

```
message.author = request.user.username
```

But when running my app and adding a message, I get this: "Cannot assign "'jose'": "Message.author" must be a "User" instance." ("jose" is my username)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use:

```
message.author = request.user
```

Comment: But will that give me the username?

Comment: That will give you the User object, then you can use message.author.username